# How can I make a class member unique for each instance created?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, object

My class member "username" must be unique for all "sellers" created? Can I implement this in the class or will it be in the main? Also both class members cannot be empty or contain spaces. Should I store all object in the list and then verify if said username already exists? I'm confused as to where I should put it.

```
Public Class Seller

Private _username As String
Private _password As String

Public Sub New(aname As String, apassword As String)
    Me.Password = apassword
    Me.UserName = anom
End Sub

Public Property Username As String
    Get
        Return _username
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Dim test As String = value
        test.Replace(" ", "")
        test.Trim()
        If (test <> value Or value = " ") Then
            Throw (New ArgumentException("Username cannot be empty or contain spaces")  
        Else
            _username = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Password As String
    Get
        Return _password
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Dim test As String = value
        test.Replace(" ", "")
        test.Trim()
        If (test <> value Or value = " ") Then
            Throw (New ArgumentException("Password cannot be empty or contain spaces")  
        Else
            _password = value
        End If

    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Thank you

Comment: one way would be to store them in a `List(Of Seller)` then scan it for a new name before creating one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` is the collection type you are looking for.

Per MSDN:

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Note: `HashSet<T>.Add()` method returns a `Boolean` (`True` if the item was added to the collection and `False` if the item is already present).

So your code should be this:

```
Dim theSellers As New HashSet(Of Seller)
Dim success As Boolean = theSellers.Add(New Seller())

' Was the addition of the Seller successful or not?     
If Not success Then
    ' No, so do something here for duplicates if you wish
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Sadly I cannot use HashSets as the assignment is to create the lists manually without using any Arrays property (I should have mentioned it in the question), but this makes sense, I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: @user2960568 - okay, well I hope this will help you later, if you feel the answer is useful, then feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: It's very unfortunate I cannot upvote because I lack the "reputation", I will come back when I have enough though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what object-oriented design says about responsibility, and the 'need to know' principle.

- Is every `Seller` object responsible for ensuring its own uniqueness?
- Is it acceptable/appropriate for every `Seller` object to check all other `Seller` objects - even to know that they exist? Or is it more useful for this object to know only about its own selling data?